# Storing session objects in Jax-Rs Jersey

Tags: java, session, jersey, jax-rs, httpsession

I am currently writing a web application using `jersey-mvc` and `jersey-mvc-freemarker`.

It is working fine , but I need a way to store session data.

On Servlets, I would use the HttpSession object, but I am wondering if there is a more JAX-RS-ish way to do it. Can someone please help?

Comment: Not sure what you are after, but `JAX-RS` is short for `Java API for RESTful Web Services` and `REST` is about being _stateless_ and this conflicts with sessions.

Comment: @sschrass No I'm not writing restful web services, but instead using Jersey as a MVC framework
 Search up HTMLEasy or jersey-mvc and you will see

Comment: okay, then: "there is no JAX-RS-ish way to store session data."

Comment: I don't know much about Jersey's internal Dependency Injection (HK2), but is there maybe a `@SessionScoped` annotation I can place on an object to share it between requests of the same session? I know of `@Singleton` and `@RequestScoped`, but I can't find a `@SessionScoped` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jersey you can add HTTP Request to your context using injection:

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
```

and then in method get `HTTPSession` object by:

```
httpRequest.getSession()
```

Comment: Actually, I am struggling to inject the HttpServletRequest into a filter of mine. When I comment out the `@Provider` annotation, my webapp starts (but fails as the filter is important). But with the filter being loaded, on startup, it crashes saying that I can not inject HttpServletRequest without a request scope. I have added the `@RequestScoped` annotation to my filter to no avail. Injection via `@Context`/`@Inject` and constructor vs field has not made any impact. Any ideas?

Comment: @vikarjramun normally this should work. Jersey supposed to inject a _proxy_ of the servlet request. You would generally only get the "no request scope" error if Jersey were trying to access methods on the request object when there is no request, e.g. inside the constructor. But if you are not using it until the `filter` method, then it should work Just fine. You can also try to inject `javax.inject.Provider<HttpServletRequest>`. This would work also. But this really shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I am still having issues, but I am going to accept your answer anyway. Thanks for the help!